# image create - part of background transparent

Tags: php

i would like to create a image with php. a specific part of the image had to be transparent.
i tried with imagecopymerge, but then i see the red background.

how i cant make a part of an image transparent?

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(1844, 1240);
$transparentBox = imagecreatefrompng('box.png');

$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);

imagecopymerge($im, $transparentBox, 93, 72, 0, 0, imagesx($transparentBox), imagesy($transparentBox), 100);


imagepng($im, './imagecolortransparent.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: i need the red background, but a part of the red background should be transparent

Comment: Can you post your image too ? (box.png)

Comment: its a transparent image 100x100px

Answer (score 2):

Use imagecopy instead:

```
 $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
 imagefilledrectangle($im, 93, 72, imagesx($transparentBox)+93, imagesy($transparentBox)+72, $black);
 imagecolortransparent($im,$black);
 imagecopy($im, $transparentBox, 93, 72, 0, 0, imagesx($transparentBox), imagesy($transparentBox));
```

Comment: didnt work for me, the transparent box is also red

Comment: Just updating answer

Comment: The updated answer, works for me. Thanks